# Convergence in distribution and convergence of variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n \overset d \equiv N(0,\sigma^2_n)$ and $X_n \overset d \rightarrow X $. Further suppose that $\sigma^2_n \overset p \rightarrow \sigma ^2>0$. Then does is follow that $X \overset d \equiv N(0,\sigma^2)$?

If not, can you give a counterexample? What if $\sigma^2_n\rightarrow \sigma^2$ in L1 or a.s.?

Thanks and regards.

EDIT: Here $\sigma^2_n$ is a random variable and $\sigma ^2$ is a constant. They are dependent to $X_n$... Is this assumption crucial?

Comment: To say that $\sigma_n^2 \to \sigma^2$ in probability or in $L^1$ or almost surely seems to presuppose that $\sigma_n^2$ and $\sigma^2$ are random variables. Did you have in mind ONLY that they are random variables of some sort, or is there something to be said about their joint or marginal distributions?

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted the proof from the classical result (which is true) in the case where your $\sigma_n$ are non random. We use the equivalence : convergence in distribution iff convergence of characteristic functions. We know from your assumption that :

$$ \mathbb{E}(e^{itX_n}) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(e^{itX}).$$

Let's compute it in another way : conditionnaly to $\sigma_n$, you have : 
$$  \mathbb{E}(e^{itX_n}) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(e^{itX_n}|\sigma_n)) = \mathbb{E}(e^{-\frac{\sigma_n^2t}{2}})$$

But then, since you have convergence in probability you can always extract a subsequence from your $\sigma_n$ converging almost surely (we will still note it $\sigma_n$) to $\sigma$, which is according to your hypothesis non random (this will be crucial). So by dominated convergence theorem :

$$\mathbb{E}(e^{itX_n}) \rightarrow  \mathbb{E}(e^{-\frac{\sigma^2t}{2}}) = e^{-\frac{\sigma^2t}{2}} $$

which is the caracteristic function of a gaussian random variable with mean 0 and variance $\sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it....
$$(X_n,\sigma_n^2)\rightarrow ^d(X,\sigma^2)$$
Hence, $$\frac{1}{\sigma_n}X_n\rightarrow ^d\frac{1}{\sigma}X$$ and $$\frac{1}{\sigma_n}X_n\rightarrow ^dN(0,1)$$

Comment: You should use your hypothesis and say you are using Slutsky's lemma.